# Azure devops query testcases using test site ID or suite name

Tags: azure-devops

in Azure devops is there a option filter testcases using Testsuite name ? Currently when i query it gives all cases then we can filter with tags etc.. so only option is we add tags to each suite and then query to get all cases for exporting

Currently adding tags to all testcases and then filtering. Would need a simpler way to filter testcases in suite

Comment: Are you able to add some screenshots to make it clearer what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are no specific test suite properties used for querying. Consider using Rest API : [Test Suites - Get Test Cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-suites/get-test-cases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP)